# How to get the innerText of RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am able to use the following to get the value of the selected radio button (of the radio button list rblReason)

```
var reasonId = $('#rblReason').find('input[checked]').val();
```

How can I get the innerText of the radio button selected?
ty

Comment: What do you want? The text that goes with the radio button? The value? The name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio button has no innerText, it is an empty element. What is your markup?

If you have a parent which contains the text you want:

```
<div> <input type="radio" name="thing" value="foo" /> Hello </div>
```

Then you could use:

```
var text= $('#rblReason input:checked').parent().text();
```

If you have a label element associated with the radio:

```
<input type="radio" name="thing" value="foo" id="thing-foo" />
<label for="thing-foo"> Hello </label>
```

then you could do:

```
var id= $('#rblReason input:checked').attr('id');
var text= $('label[for='+id+']').text();
```

Note, use `:checked` to see which checkbox/radio is currently selected. `[checked]` means testing that the element has a `checked` attribute, which will always return the initially-checked radio regardless of what the user has selected. [Except in IE, due to a bug.]

Comment: Thank you this was the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @Bobince: What if there are two radio buttons within that div(ss is usually the case)? This is not going to work then. It will return the text for both those items.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Walk the DOM as necessary for whatever markup you've got. For example if you have `<input> some text <input> some text`, get `input_node.nextSibling.textContent` (`innerText` for IE). Better if possible: fix the markup to include a `<label>` element. It's more accessible and easier to access in jQuery (which isn't good at dealing with text nodes).